# Create Employee account in Quick Books

Tags: web-services, desktop, quickbooks

I want to create an account for each employee registered in quick books.
Can I do this? 
if not ?
How can i post journal entry to employee account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a programming problem. This question could better be asked to their customer service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. If you're trying to see how much each employee has been paid over time it's under the "Reports" tab on the left>all reports>total pay. That shows hourly or salary for example.

When employees are paid, a journal entry is created for each payment automatically. However, you can still create an account for each employee by opening the "banking" tab on the left menu and finding the payroll transaction in the list of imported banking entries. Before you verify the transaction, click in the accounts empty box and choose "add-new." This will create extra accounting work for you though, I recommend not creating new accounts for employees if you already have them registered through the "employees" tab on the left menu.

[Here](http://payroll.intuit.com/support/kb/1000304.html) is the quickbooks help page for registering employees if you haven't already.

To post journal entries to ANY account it can be found under the "chart of accounts" on the left tab. Quickbooks automatically makes accounts for payroll employees if you want to make an adjustment. In the chart of accounts look under the "Payroll Expenses" for the account of the employee whose journal you want to adjust.